# how is char * to string literal valid?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, initialization

So from my understanding pointer variables point to an address. So, how is the following code valid in C++?

```
char* b= "abcd"; //valid
int *c= 1; //invalid
```

Comment: You better use `const char*`for *b* unless you intend to change the characters in the string.

Comment: Pick one language, not two. C and C++ are different here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C and very old versions of C++, a string literal `"abcd"` is of type `char[]`, a character array. Such an array can naturally get pointed at by a `char*`, but not by a `int*` since that's not a compatible type.

However, C and C++ are different, often incompatible programming languages. They dropped compatibility with each other some 20 years ago.

In standard C++, a string literal is of type `const char[]` and therefore none of your posted code is valid in C++. This won't compile:

```
char* b = "abcd";        //invalid, discards const qualifier
```

This will:

```
const char* c = "abcd";  // valid
```

Comment: so the c pointer will point to "abcd" isn't pointer supposed to point at the address or else it will output an error if pointed to anything else?

Comment: @sorryiamrookie It will point at the address where the literal `"abcd"` is stored. Which, as it turns out, is a read-only address. So if you attempt to modify the contents there, the program might crash. Therefore it is good practice to always use `const char* c` when pointing at string literals, in C and C++ both.

Comment: To be more precise, in this particular case, conversion of a string literal to a non-`const` pointer was deprecated in C++03 (i.e. it was still legal but slated for removal in a future standard) and finally removed in C++11.   A consequence of this is that code using such a conversion would legally compile until C++11, but compilers would (if configured appropriately to give warnings) give a warning about it.   Such an implicit conversion is illegal in C++, so will not compile, only since C++11.

Comment: In c you have to always compile with gcc flag ` -Wwrite-strings` to check and warn you in case you forget the const for literals but in C++ is enabled by default.

Answer (score 7):

The first line

```
 char* b= "abcd";
```

is valid in C, because "string literals", while used as initializer, boils down to the address of the first element in the literal, which is a pointer (to `char`).

Related, `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, string literals,

> [...] The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an **array** of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   type `char`, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence. [...]

and then, chapter §6.3.2.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> **Except when** it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or **is a string literal used to initialize an array**, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

However, as mentioned in comments, in `C++11` onwards, this is not valid anymore as string literals are of type `const char[]` there and in your case, LHS lacks the `const` specifier.

OTOH,

```
 int *c= 1;
```

is invalid (illegal) because, `1` is an integer constant, which is not the same type as `int *`.

Comment: Note that assigning a string literal to a **non-const** `char*` pointer is deprecated in C++11.

Comment: BTW, it's only valid C++ before C++11; after that, dropping the `const` was disallowed.

Comment: OK, I was concentrating on the C tag..Will add this info into the answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it was deprecated in C++03, and an error in C++11

Answer (score 1):

`"abcd"` is actually a `const char[5]` type, and the language permits this to be assigned to a `const char*` (and, regrettably, a `char*` although C++11 onwards disallows it.).

`int *c = 1;` is not allowed by the C++ or C standards since you can't assign an `int` to an `int*` pointer (with the exception of `0`, and in that case your intent will be expressed clearer by assigning `nullptr` instead).

Comment: Oops. Time for a coffee.

Comment: @M.M. Time for another coffee - perhaps I'll dig out my university notes out from the loft at the weekend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`"abcd"` is the address that contains the sequence of five bytes `97 98 99 100 0` -- you cannot see what the address is in the source code, but the compiler will still assign it an address.

`1` is also an address near the bottom of your [virtual] memory. This may not seem to be useful to you, but it is [useful to other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618271/access-memory-mapped-i-o), so even though the "standard" might not want to permit this, every compiler you are ever likely to run into will support this.

Comment: The string literal (an array essentially) will decay to a pointer type due to interoperability rules. An int will not decay into a pointer-to-int. Have you tried compiling the code on "every compiler"? Mine certainly won't. (Thankfully)

Comment: " sequence of five bytes 97 98 99 100 0" - assuming a particular *encoding*, not guaranteed. The last byte is always 0 though.

Comment: @sigbjornlo Yours most certainly will with the right prompting, because this sort of code is still quite common.

Comment: @Bathsheba What part of sorryiamrookie's question made you think that they have any access to a non-ASCII system?

Comment: The tags on the question.

Comment: Got it. Most people program C or C++ on computers, instead of fantasy machines like the ones you're thinking of @Bathsheba

Comment: But all you have to add is "assuming ASCII encoding" and your answer takes an order of magnitude leap in credibility.

Comment: At the expense of being less helpful to the asker of the question. I stopped trying to prove how smart I am to beginners over twenty years ago.

Comment: That's a pity. Portability considerations are amongst the most important part of programming in C and C++. Us experienced folk ought never incept any ideas to the contrary to anyone; especially beginners. Indeed newer generation languages (e.g. Java) make portability less of a concern.

Comment: The most important thing is solving the problem you have to solve. If you are solving a problem you don't have, and have no reason to think you have, you're wasting time and money. Teaching people to think they'll always (or almost always) save time and money by spending it now making it portable is just cargo/cult programming and anathema.

Comment: @geocar Cajoling the compiler into accepting `int* p = 1` is not the way to go about it, `reinterpret_cast<int*>(1)` is the purposefully ugly construct that should be used if you are sitting on arguably "common" code that needs to handle addresses as numbers. While it's certainly helpful to show people what _can_ be done, it's better to answer entry-level questions with what probably _should_ be done.

Comment: @sigbjornlo every C compiler will accept it by default, and whilst I agree that we should show people what should be done, I think that typing things the programmer doesn't understand doesn't facilitate understanding.

Answer (score 0):

While all other answers give the correct answer of why you code doesn't work, using a *compound literal* to initialize `c`, is one way you can make your code work, e.g.

```
int *c= (int[]){ 1 };
printf ("int pointer c : %d\n", *c);
```

Note, there are differences between C and C++ in the use of compound literals, they are only available in C.

Comment: While very correct, this is probably not what OP is looking for. There is a difference between `"abcd"` and `1` and OP looks to be interested in that. :)

Comment: It was kind of hard to tell. This was the only way I could think of to initialize an `int *` from a literal `1`, in order to make what it looked like he was trying to do -- work.

Comment: The `int *c= (int[]){ 1 };` takes the address of a temporary array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin as I said, you are not at all wrong, it's just IMHO, not in the correct context, that's all. Again, it's just my opinion.

Comment: No, not a temporary array, it is a `cast` to and `integer array` initialized with the universal initializer. There is nothing temporary about it. It is an array created on the stack with `c` being a pointer to that array holding `1` as its first element.

Comment: By "subtle differences" you mean that C has compound literals and C++ does not

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I completely get what you were saying, you guys provided good answer as to why what he did didn't work. I did not duplicate your work in my answer. I just thought it important for the OP to know how to make his `int *c` initialization work, rather than approaching from the flip-side of the coin and explaining why what he did, didn't work.

Comment: @Akira the array lasts as long as `c` does (lifetime of the same block it was created in)